# Is there a way to extract objects (class instances) in JavaScript to Android using WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am trying to extract objects and lists created in JavaScript to use them inside Android application. (I have succeeded in extracting single values.) I am using addJavaScriptInterface method to implement this.

Inside test.html, I have the following script code:
(I've tried without ".slice()" but did not work either)

```
function getList(){
var categoryTotals = {};
categoryTotals[0] = 1;
categoryTotals[1] = 2;
categoryTotals[2] = 3;
return categoryTotals.slice();
}
```

And the WebViewClient's onPageFinished method contains the following code:

```
mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.callAndroidList(getList());");
```

My JavaScriptInterface has the following function:

```
public void callAndroidList(final List list){
        myList = list;
        Log.d("ListTest" , "LIST 1 >>>>>>>>>>>>> " + ListTest.myList.get(0));
        Log.d("ListTest" , "LIST 2 >>>>>>>>>>>>> " + ListTest.myList.get(1));
        Log.d("ListTest" , "LIST 3 >>>>>>>>>>>>> " + ListTest.myList.get(2));
    }
```

When I run this code, I get NullPointerException saying that callAndroidList's parameter, list, is null. I haven't dealt much with JavaScript so I think it is possible that this is related to creation and removal of JavaScript object instances.

Could you help me out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
> function getList(){ 
>     var categoryTotals = {};
```

That will create an object, I think you mean to create an array, so perhaps it should be:

```
      var categoryTotals = [];
```

.

```
>     categoryTotals[0] = 1;
>     categoryTotals[1] = 2;
>     categoryTotals[2] = 3;
>     return categoryTotals.slice();
```

Since you are creating an object with numeric properties, not an array, it does not have a *slice* method. Initializing *categoryTotals* as an array should fix that.

Incidentally, there does not seem to be any point in using *slice* to return a copy of the array. Since *categoryTotals* is not used for anything else, why not just return it?

Comment: I tried it after changing it to brackets, and it still doesn't work. I first tried without .slice() and kept giving me NullPointerException. I thought if I could pass the actual object rather than just a reference, I could solve the problem; so, I tried slice method but it was no good.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you "return" either *categoryTotals* or *categoryTotals.slice()*, the **value** being returned will be a reference to an object.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that's what was happening. I guess I have no other choice but to change them to String values and pass them. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You might consider [JSON](http://www.json.org) to return a string - javascript has a built-in *JSON.stringify*. Essentially you'll be serialising the response so it can be converted back to an object or array later.